# how to print excel file via vb6?

Tags: excel, printing, vb6

I have an excel file that was created by vb6 application and after I save it, I want it to be printed into the default printer..,

Tnx, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should accept answers from your previous questions if you want to have any answer to your new ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSH As Excel.Worksheet

    'open excel application
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    'Open excel workbook
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\YourFile.xls")
    'There are two ways to access specific worksheets
    'By index number (the first worksheet in this case)
    Set xlSH = xlWB.Worksheets(1)
    'or by the Sheet's Name
    Set xlSH = xlWB.Worksheets("TestSheet")

    PrintSheet xlSH, "MyFoot", "MyHead"

    'Close workbook (optional)
    xlWB.Close
    'Quit excel (automatically closes all workbooks)
    xlApp.Quit
    'Clean up memory (you must do this)
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub PrintSheet(sh As Worksheet, strFooter As String, strHeader As String)
    sh.PageSetup.CenterFooter = strFooter
    sh.PageSetup.CenterHeader = strHeader
    sh.PrintOut
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet, to answer your question, you can use :

```
ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

and you can find much information here : http://www.exceltip.com/excel_tips/Printing_in_VBA/210.html

Anyway, i insist, you should accept answers from your previous questions or people won't care answering your new ones.

Max

Comment: @rekcah101 - if this is the solution then you need to mark it as the answer

Comment: @ JMax - yeh.., that's why my reputation doesn't  goes up.., tnx alot bro